# "Could not find Installable ISAM" error connecting to Jet.OLEDB from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

Can anyone help in accessing a database using Javascript. The `.mdb` file is password protected, and I am using `OLEDB` to access the database.

```
conn.open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\\db\\D1.mdb;Database password=pass");
```

The line above gives me this error :

```
Could not find Installable ISAM.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) you need to use `Jet OLEDB:Database Password=`, as in

```javascript
conn.open ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\\db\\D1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass");
```